# mysql_fetch_assoc skipping the first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this problem. when I fetch the data from the SQL result, it skips the first row. No idea why, since i don't call mysql_fetch_assoc() earlier in the code.

```
    $requete1 = "SELECT * FROM objet o JOIN type t ON o.type_obj = t.lib_type
    WHERE salle ='$idSalle'";
    $resultat1 = mysql_query($requete1) or die("Pb requête ".mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultat1) > 0){
        while ($array0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat1)) {
            echo 'whatever'.$array0['id_obj'];
        };
    };
```

EDIT:
Resulting echo :

```
whatever2
whatever3
whatever4
...
```

The first id_obj in the table is 1. I'd like it to be displayed.

There is really not much I could add to that, everything is just there!

Here is the displayed result, as you can see "Port Number" starts at 2 although 1 exists
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/f04Tm.png

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. You'll have to provide more information and proof about what you expect to happen exactly and why.

Comment: Is this working code? Why you have `array0` instead of `$array0` ? Are you 100% sure that for this query results are different that those displayed using echo?

Comment: I'm sorry Marcin I just messed while copying the code

Comment: Apparently the problem was lower, I was calling the function twice... thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use proper syntex of join: 
Please refer : [click Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer:

```
$requete1 = "SELECT * FROM objet o left outer JOIN type t ON o.type_obj = t.lib_type
    WHERE salle ='$idSalle'";
    $resultat1 = mysql_query($requete1) or die("Pb requête ".mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultat1) > 0){
        while ($array0 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultat1)) {
            echo 'whatever'.array0['id_obj'];
        };
    };
```

Comment: It didn't changes anything, sorry